# If $C_G(x) \leq H$ for every $p$-element $x \in H$, then $p$ cannot divide both $|H|$ and $|G:H|$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is problem 1.D.2 in Isaacs, [Finite Group Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821843443). I am self-studying, so would appreciate a proof verification.

**Note:** in this book, all groups are assumed finite unless otherwise stated.

> Fix a prime $p$, and suppose that a subgroup $H \leq G$ has the property that $C_G(x) \leq H$ for every element $x \in H$ having order $p$. Show that $p$ cannot divide both $|H|$ and $|G:H|$.

**My proof:** Suppose that $p$ divides both $|H|$ and $|G:H|$. Let $P \in Syl_p(H)$. Since $p$ divides $|G:H|$, we see that $P$ cannot be in $Syl_p(G)$ (its order is too small), but it must be contained in some $Q \in Syl_p(G)$.

Let $N = N_Q(P)$. Since $P < Q$ and $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup, we have $P < N \leq Q$ since "normalizers grow" in finite $p$-groups (because they are nilpotent).

Let $N$ act on $P$ by conjugation. Suppose that $y \in P$ is a nonidentity element which is fixed by this action, i.e., $\{y\}$ is a one-point orbit. Then every element of $\langle y \rangle$ is also fixed, since, for example, $gy^2g^{-1} = (gyg^{-1})(gyg^{-1}) = y^2$. Since $\langle y \rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup, it contains some $x$ of order $p$. Since $x$ is fixed by the action, it is centralized by $N$. This means that $N \leq C_G(x)$. Since $C_G(x) \leq H$ by hypothesis, we have $P < N \leq H$. But this is impossible because $P \in Syl_p(H)$ and $N$ is a $p$-subgroup which properly contains $N$. We conclude that $1$ is the only fixed point in this action.

Now by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, we have $|P| = 1 + \text{stuff divisible by }p$. Taking this equation modulo $p$, we obtain the contradiction $0 \equiv 1 \mod p$.

Comment: It looks OK to me. There is a general result that if $N$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of a $p$-group $P$, then $N \cap Z(P)$ is nontrivial. You can shortened your proof by using that, but the proof of that result is esentially the argument you used.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you, I do have that result available; it's the first result proved by Isaacs in this section. I'll review his proof (maybe I subconsciously reproduced it) and try to use the result to shorten my proof when I get the chance later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks good! Here is another one.

Assume $p$ divides $|H|$. We will show that $p$ cannot divide $|G:H|$. Let $P \in Syl_p(H)$, which exists and is non-trivial, since $p \mid |H|$. Put $\Omega = \{x \in P : \text { order}(x)=p\}$. Then $|\Omega| \equiv -1 $(mod $p$) (this follows from the McKay proof of Cauchy's Theorem).

$N_G(P)$ acts on $\Omega$ by conjugation. Let $\{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$ be a set of representatives of the orbits of this action. Then
$$|\Omega|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|N_G(P):C_{N_G(P)}(x_i)|.$$
Since $C_G(x_i) \subseteq H$ by assumption, we have for every $i$:
$$C_{N_G(P)}(x_i)=C_G(x_i) \cap N_G(P) \subseteq H \cap N_G(P)=N_H(P).$$
In particular $|N_G(P) : N_H(P)|$ divides $|N_G(P) : C_{N_G(P)}(x_i)|$ for every i, whence $|N_G(P) : N_H(P)|$ divides $|\Omega|$.
Then since $|\Omega| \equiv -1$ (mod $p$), $|N_G(P) : N_H(P)|$ cannot be divisible by $p$.

On the other hand, $|N_H(P) : P|$ is not divisible by $p$ as $P \in Syl_p(H)$, so $p$ does not divide $|N_G(P) : N_H(P)| \dot |N_H(P) : P| = |N_G(P) : P|$.

Finally (see Exercise 1.A.10 is Isaacs' book!), $|N_G(P):P| \equiv |G:P|$ mod $p$. Therefore $p$ cannot divide $|G:H|$.

Comment: Thanks! I had to think for a few minutes about why $|\Omega| \equiv -1$ (mod $p$), but now I see that it's correct. (I don't think I would have noticed this if you had not pointed it out, though!) I'm at work now, so verifying your final statement will have to wait until I get home. I think I did 1.A.10 but I don't remember the proof.

Comment: For future reference, here is the reason why $|\Omega| \equiv -1$ (mod $p$). As in the McKay proof, we consider the set $A$ of all $p$-tuples $(x_1, x_2, \ldots,x_p)$ such that each $x_n \in G$ and $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_p = 1$. We can choose $x_1$ through $x_{p-1}$ freely, then $x_p$ is uniquely determined, so $A$ has order $|G|^{p-1}$. Then $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$ acts on $A$ by cyclic shifting. The fixed points are those $p$-tuples for which $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots x_p$. By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the number of fixed points is congruent to $0$ mod $p$. (continued...)

Comment: ...Therefore the number of elements $x \in G$ for which $x^p = 1$ is congruent to $0$ mod $p$. Excluding $x = 1$, this means that the number of elements of order $p$ is congruent to $-1$ mod $p$.

Comment: Bungo, great job! This is totally correct!!

Comment: Yep, I did 1.A.10. For completeness and future reference, here is a sketch of the proof. Let $\Lambda$ be the set of right cosets of $P$ (i.e. $\Lambda = G/P$), and let $P$ act on $\Lambda$ by right multiplication. The fixed points under this action are precisely the cosets in $N_G(P) / P$, and $|\Lambda| = |G:P|$, so the orbit-stabilizer theorem taken mod $p$ gives us $|G:P| \equiv |N_G(P) : P|$ mod $p$. Thanks again for this alternative proof! I considered an action on your $\Omega$ but I didn't see how to quantify $|\Omega|$.

Comment: Nice, as I work my way through the problems in this section, I reach 1.D.12, which is none other than to prove that $|\Omega| \equiv -1$ (mod $p$). I think I will take the evening off to celebrate :-)